# Angular: pass service from custom element to child custom element

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, custom-element, angular-dependency-injection

I have build a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-custom-elements-wcj7em?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbar%2Fbar-ce.component.ts) which creates 2 custom angular elements (checkout app.module). Works like a charm, but there is one problem, if I provide a service in the parent element (called BarComponent), it is not received by the its child CE (called TestComponent)

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './bar-ce.component.html',
  providers: [TestService] // <-- this one!!
})
export class BarComponent {}
```

Inside its html it renders the child CE: `TEST-CE: <test-ce></test-ce>`

If I try to inject my **TestService** this way I get the "NullInjectorError: No provider for TestService!"

But if I provide it inside the app.module it all works again. So my question is, is there a way to fix this or is this just the way it is with CE (hope not)?

Answer (score 1):

You should fix your problem doing like this according to your demo.

```
TEST-CE: <test-ce [testService]="testService"></test-ce>
```

And then on your child component doing like this.

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { TestService } from '../test.service';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() testService: TestService

  numInput: number;

  constructor() { 
    console.log('test-ce constructor.');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.numInput = this.testService.value;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shared service should be provided in module. And latar initialize in constructor (private testService: Testservice)

Comment: are you sure about that? Because this is a very legitimate way to share services if not using CE apparently